# How do you make abstract amorphous color backgrounds in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, graphics, photoshop-cs5

I see amorphous color field like wallpapers all the time, how do people make them?

Examples are [here](http://browse.deviantart.com/customization/wallpaper/minimalistic/?qh=&section=&q=blue%20abstract#/d35ki84):

[image]

… and [here](http://browse.deviantart.com/customization/wallpaper/minimalistic/?qh=&section=&q=blue%20abstract#/d388uto):

[image]

Comment: Just one example: [Create Abstract Backgrounds in Illustrator | Vectips](http://vectips.com/tutorials/create-abstract-backgrounds/), that's Illustrator though — similar tutorials surely exist for Photoshop. Have you looked online?

Answer (score 0):

To make general amorphous structures I like to use the Render Clouds functionality of Photoshop:

See [Here](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~parsec/information/photoshoptutorial-clouds/)

On top of those "clouds" you can add color and gradients and create all kinds of abstract backgrounds.